# Remove a Model from List of model with in source model elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Below is the code I am using:

```
"_source" : {
    "name" : "hn name",
    "user_id" : 553,
    "email_id" : "ns@gmail.com",
    "lres_id" : "",
    "hres_id" : "hn image",
    "followers" : 0,
    "following" : 1,
    "mentors" : 2,
    "mentees" : 2,
    "basic_info" : "hn developer",
    "birth_date" : 1448451985397,
    "charge_price" : 3000,
    "org" : "mnc pvt ltd",
    "located_in" : "Noidasec51 ",
    "position" : "jjunior ava developer",
    "requests" : 0,
    "exp" : 5,
    "video_bio_lres" : "hn test lres url",
    "video_bio_hres" : "hn hres url",
    "ratings" : [ {
      "rating" : 1,
      "ratedByUserId" : 777
    }, {
      "rating" : 1,
      "ratedByUserId" : 555
    } ],
    "avg_rating" : 0.0,
    "status" : 0,
    "expertises" : [ 3345, 1234, 2345 ],
    "blocked_users" : [ ]
  }
```

In the Following Code, I want to delete rating ratedByUserId 555 only.But Some How I am unable for doing so.
How to do it?

Comment: its working...   curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/mentorz/users/555/_update' -d '{"script":"ctx._source.ratings.remove(ratings)","params":{"ratings":{"rating":1,"ratedByUserId":555}}}';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its works for me:-
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/mentorz/users/555/_update' -d
'{"                                                                                                                                                                                    script":"ctx._source.ratings.remove(ratings)",
"params":{
"‌​ratings":{
"rating":1‌​,
"ratedByUserId":555‌​
}
}
}'